# Garbage Disposal / Plumbing Dilemma

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I just purchased a new garbage disposal.
The current plumbing will not allow the new disposal to fit in place.
The main sewage line with a wye is in the way and I need to replace it.
This is a single sink single trap set up.

Questions:

1. what is the best way to do this (see picture)
2. Can I cut the wye pipe just before the base and then use a saw of some sort to cut the remaining flange around the bottom?
3. Or, should I just cut the whole wye pipe out and install a new one?

[image]

[image: Existing PVC Connection]

Comment: Added new picture.

Answer (score 1):

Anything could be possible. The benefit of the wye, the way it is setup, is for cleaning. If you don't forsee any future problems with cleaning, I would cut it out, and use a threaded set of pipes. This way you can still remove the pipes if you need to clean it out and if you need to make any adjustments to the drain, this will make it easier to do. Once you figure out the height needed for the disposal, you can re-plumb the drain. But make sure you still have room for your p-trap setup.

Also, is this a single sink or a double? Perhaps if a double sink, have you thought about reversing the drain and disposal setup?

Comment: I'm not sure you've answered the question, which largely involves the demolition stage. Obviously something needs to be cut. Where are you suggesting?

Comment: Without seeing more of the "picture", OP could cut above the joint, below the joint, heck, below the floor of the cabinet, or even below the sub floor of the structure. It all depends on how far down they want to go. So where to cut is a relative term. But as I indicated, cut it out. Simply that you cut out the wye. Where? Of course where needed to remove it from the system. I did say, "If you don't forsee any future problems with cleaning, I would cut it out, and use a threaded set of pipes." I also asked if the sink is setup in a way as to not require cutting.

Comment: I saw the replies on the road and decided there was enough pipe under the floor that I just took a saws all and cut out the Wye and then rebuild the plumbing so the new garbage disposal would fit. I appreciate the input.

Comment: @ChristopherLond since this answer seems to have given you the info you needed to resolve your problem, the appropriate way to show you "appreciate the input" is to click the up-vote arrow and the check-mark. That also shows others that this question has a workable answer so they can look at it to resolve their similar issues.